# Why is styleguide not applicable for class extending core classes in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

In the [Codeigniter style-guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming), it clearly states that the class names should be named in a **Ucfirst-like** manner like *Hello_world* (not *Hello_World*).

But for [extending core classes](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html#extending-core-class), it advise us to use names like *MY_Controller* which is against the style-guide.

What might be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

All core classes follow the second name pattern you mention. E.g. *CI_Controller*,
*CI_Exceptions*, *CI_Model*, *CI_Output*.

Extended core classes are meant to perform the same role that the core classes, and there's a clear difference between a core class and a regular one.

So I guess the reason is obvious, if you see a XX_Xxxxxx name pattern you will automatically know it is a core (or extended core) class.